# Can we treat Gazeau-Klauder coherent states for infinite potential well as a superposition of Fock states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-optics, coherent-states

If we define coherent states of infinite potential well based on Gazeau-Klauder coherent states. Can we use ladder operators and bosonic algebra for them which we use for Glauber coherent states?